# Python pandas dataframes - trying to access/print certain fields from read_csv causes a type error - how to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Whenever I try to run a simple print operation on a variable within my data frame, it displays the following errors:

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

and then:

> KeyError: 'Value'

I know this field exists in my dataframe because I have printed the results of it

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 

iColumns = 7

szTransactionFile = 'Exports/example03.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(szTransactionFile, index_col=None, skiprows=1, usecols=range(iColumns), escapechar='\'', lineterminator='\n')
df.drop(index=0, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={list(df)[6]: 'Account Number'}, inplace=True)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     print("Value: " + row['Value'])
```

These are the contents of the csv:

```
Date, Type, Description, Value, Balance, Account Name, Account Number
,,,,,,
05/08/2020,POS,"1234 03AUG20 , PAY *NAME, 2135655",-20,28.4,bobsley bobbington,1234
04/08/2020,POS,"1234 03AUG20 , WWW.AMAZON.COM, 123 123 132 42 GG",-15.99,48.4,bobsley bobbington,1234
03/08/2020,POS,"1234 29JUL20 C , STORE, CHINA GG",-3.3,64.39,bobsley bobbington,1234
03/08/2020,POS,"1234 24JUL20 C , IZ *KING , NORWAY GG",-5.3,67.69,bobsley bobbington,1234
30/07/2020,D/D,'PAYPAL PAYMENT,-1.99,72.99,bobsley bobbington,1234
```

Please could someone help me with this one? I am confused because I can access row['Date'] and row['Account Number] in the iterator, but none of the other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have leading *space* in column names

```
data = '''Date, Type, Description, Value, Balance, Account Name, Account Number,,
05/08/2020,POS,"1234 03AUG20 , PAY *NAME, 2135655",-20,28.4,bobsley bobbington,1234
04/08/2020,POS,"1234 03AUG20 , WWW.AMAZON.COM, 123 123 132 42 GG",-15.99,48.4,bobsley bobbington,1234
03/08/2020,POS,"1234 29JUL20 C , STORE, CHINA GG",-3.3,64.39,bobsley bobbington,1234
03/08/2020,POS,"1234 24JUL20 C , IZ *KING , NORWAY GG",-5.3,67.69,bobsley bobbington,1234
30/07/2020,D/D,'PAYPAL PAYMENT,-1.99,72.99,bobsley bobbington,1234'''
a = [[i for i in l.split(",")] for l in data.split("\n")]
df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])
df.loc[:, ['Date', ' Type', ' Description', ' Value', ' Balance', ' Account Name',
       ' Account Number', '', '']]
df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]
df.loc[:, ['Date', 'Type', 'Description', 'Value', 'Balance', 'Account Name',
       'Account Number', '', '']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can't believe I missed it. Do you think it could be possible to solve this using regex in the seperator/delimiter parameter in read_csv using regex? Or would it be too complicated given sometimes there is a leading space and sometimes there isn't?

Comment: You could make your column rename smarter of use what I did with list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot convert `int` value to `str` automatically.
You can do :

```
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
     print("Value: " + str(row['Value']))
```